# Wireguard peer not accessible by other peers, while every other peer can connect to each other, why?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have a Wireguard setup of a few PCs, let's call them A, B, C, D.

A is the server or hub, being publicly accessible and has all the others as peers.
B, C and D are all peers that are not publicly accessible and thus they can only connect to each other trough A.

Connecting from B to C and back is working without any problems, but neither of them can access D.

The tunnel is working because A can access D without problems.

A is running on Windows 10, with forwarding enabled and firewall disabled.

The peers are running different Linuxes.

I tried ssh, nc, tcpdump but none of them seem to receive any traffic. On windows using Wireshark I receive the packets from the other peers and I get an ICMP redirect packet.

Any ideas what I could try out?

None of the peers have firewall rules that could interfere...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I used the config from the server as the base for the config of D and forgot that if I don't remove the other peers from it the routing will not work as expected!

Lesson learned, always write the config from scratch